# Norton Method Problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/EECS.6.002x/asset/images_circuits_sensor-norton.gif]

$$ I = 1.43 \mu A  \space \space R_p=1.8M\Omega  \space\space R_s = 17k\Omega$$

I am trying to find the Norton current. This seems like a simple problem, but I keep getting it wrong.

I tried using current divider: 
$$ 1.43 \mu A \cdot \frac{34k\Omega}{ 1.8M\Omega} = 0.027 \mu A$$
Yet the actual answer is $$1.40348964013 \mu A?$$

I am just wondering what I did wrong?

Comment: Woah! [Significant Figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

Comment: That's what I was going to say. I actually have a professor that wants exactly 6 "significant figures" after the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current divider equation is wrong.

The current through the 17K + 17K resistor pair (with output short circuited) is :$$ 1.43 \mu A \cdot \frac{1.8M\Omega}{ 1.8M\Omega +34K\Omega} = 1.40348964013 \mu A$$

Comment: Why is it over 1.8megaohms and not 34kohms?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider